# Passing down MediaWiki template arguments to custom HTML attributes

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

Consider a custom MediaWiki extension that adds a new tag named `simplified_example` with some JavaScript (just calling `alert` with provided argument for simplicity):

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) die();

$wgExtensionFunctions[] = 'registerTags';
$wgExtensionCredits['parserhook'][] = array(
    'name' => 'myTags',
);

function registerTags() {
    global $wgParser;
    $wgParser->setHook('simplified_example', function ($input, $argv, $parser, $frame) {
        $output = $parser->recursiveTagParse($input, $frame);
        $title = $argv["value"];
        return "<div onclick=\"alert('$title')\">$output</div>";
    });
}
?>
```

Using that I can put following code in a MediaWiki page source:

```
<simplified_example value="Testing">...</simplified_example>
```

This results with `...` div being clickable - a message box with provided text is displayed. Now I wanted to place this tag inside a template, like this:

```
<simplified_example value="{{{1}}}">...</simplified_example>
```

When I put this template into a MediaWiki page:

```
{{TestTemplate|Testing...}}
```

Once again I obtain a clickable `...` but displayed message is not evaluated and `{{{1}}}` is displayed instead of provided `Testing...`.

How can I pass the argument from MediaWiki page source down to my custom tag through a template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `#tag` function instead of html in your template, like this:

> {{#tag:simplified_example|value={{{1}}} }}